# customer registration not showing in django admin

Tags: python, django

Trying to create customer registration form for ecommerce website . No errors while submitting the form, but details are not shown in django admin . Here are required codes :

**models.py**

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    joined_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [path("register",views.register, name="register")]
```

**forms.py**

```
class CustomerRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput())

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ["username", "password", "email", "full_name", "address"]

    def clean_username(self):
        uname = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
        if User.objects.filter(username=uname).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "Customer with this username already exists.")

        return uname
```

**views.py**

```
def register(request):
    form = CustomerRegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
     username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
     password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
     email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
     user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
     form.instance.user = user
     return redirect("/")

    return render(request,"register.html",{'form':form})
```

**register.html**

```
    {% load crispy_forms_tags %} 
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
            <h3>Customer Registration Form</h3><hr>
            <form action="" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{form|crispy}}
                <button class="btn btn-primary" >Register as a Customer</button>
            </form>
            <p> Already have an account? <a href="/home">Login here</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Thank you in advance:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view, you're creating `User`s, not `Customer`s.

If you're starting a new project, I would suggest using a [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

If that's not possible, you need to save the form first to generate a `Customer` instance and then connect it with the appropriate `User` model:

```py
def register(request):
    form = CustomerRegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
        email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
        customer = form.save(commit=False)
        user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
        customer.user = user
        customer.save()
        form.instance.user = user
        return redirect("/")

    return render(request,"register.html",{'form':form})
```